# Заполнение динамически создаваемых элементов

Tags: android, android-layout

Я создал "кастомный" `layout`, в котором будут динамически создаваться элементы и отображаться на экране приложения. Приложение работает, в цикле создаются указанное кол-во элементов и затем они отображаются.

Но мне надо, чтобы в этих элементах - `Button`, `EditText` и пр. - отображался некий текст (для примера, создал класс и несколько его объектов, и поля этих объектов должны отображаться в элементах: в первом элементе - имя первого объекта, во втором - второго и т.д.).

Проблема в том, что в итоге, когда все элементы созданы, заполнен только первый элемент, но текстом последнего указанного объекта.

Пример:

```
for (counter = 0; counter < 3; counter++) {
    final View view = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.custom_edittext_layout, null);
    EditText text = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.editText);
    text.setText(counter);
    allEds.add(view);
    linear.addView(view);
}
```

В результате этого кода будут созданы 3 `EditText`, при этом текст установится в первый, и этим текстом будет цифра 2 (а нужно, чтобы в первом было 0, во втором-1, в третьем-2).

Как сделать так, чтобы заполнялся каждый создаваемый элемент, и они получили каждый свой текст?

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private List<View> allEds;
    private int counter = 0;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        ScrollView sv = new ScrollView(this);
        LinearLayout ll = new LinearLayout(this);
        ll.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
        sv.addView(ll);

        Button addButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button16);
        allEds = new ArrayList<View>();

        final LinearLayout linear = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.linear);
        for (counter = 0; counter < 3; counter++) {
            final View view = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.custom_edittext_layout, null);
            Button deleteField = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.buttonc);
            EditText text = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.editText);
            text.setText(counter);
            allEds.add(view);
            linear.addView(view);
        }
    }
}
```

Вот текст `layout`'-а, в котором отображаются элементы:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/editText"
        android:text="Empty"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/textView" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="X"
        android:id="@+id/buttonc"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/editText"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:text="Nameobject"
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/editText" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:text="Min"
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/editText"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/editText" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Прежде всего задайтесь вопросом: необходимо ли для решения Вашей задачи создавать отдельные `View` таким образом? Может стоить воспользоваться `RecyclerView`?

Если все-таки нужен первый вариант, то читайте дальше.

Вы как-то весьма странно создаете новые `EditText`. Вместо создания нового `EditText` Вы получаете уже существующий `EditText`:

```
EditText text = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.editText);
```

и изменяете его.

Для создания и отображения `EditText` необходимо:

1. Создать инстанс класса `EditText`;
2. Установить для него `layout`-параметры (параметры того, как он будет отображен относительно родительского `View`);
3. Добавить созданный объект в родительское представление.

Вот Вам простой пример динамического создания с последующим отображением трех `EditText`:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    LinearLayout mLinearLayout;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        mLinearLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.activity_main);

        for (int i=0; i<3; i++) {
            addNewEditText("New EditText #" + i);
        }
    }

    public void addNewEditText(String text) {
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        EditText editText = new EditText(this);
        editText.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
        editText.setText(text);
        mLinearLayout.addView(editText);
    }
}
```